# P4Sandbox configuration error - "too many users"

Tags: perforce

I have configured a p4sandbox a long time ago on my laptop. This doesn't map the whole depot. I have recently added a new project to my sandbox, and I want to push this back to the main depot on my server.

In the dashboard, I chose to copy up my changes to the mirror, but when I come to submit, I get a the following failure:

> Submit validation failed -- fix problems then use 'p4 submit -c 83'.
>   'trigger-00' validation failed: Message from central server xxxx:1666
>   file.sln - file(s) not in client view. Submit of changes
>   to central server failed; submit was aborted

So my next step was to go and edit the workspace setting (as it seemed to complain about that) but because of streams it seems I cannot edit the workspace without editing the stream path mappings. So I go to configure p4sandbox, and select my sandbox.

This works fine on my desktop, but my laptop complains with a popup saying "Error - too many users".

My questions are (a) am I actually doing the right thing to get my files into the depot (b) has anyone seen this p4sandbox error? Googling seems to not turn up the message.

Thanks

Comment: The sandbox runs with two user accounts, your own and a system one.  If you try to have a third user it will fail.  Are you sharing a sandbox between two computers?  Perhaps you have different user names on the two systems?  A call to Perforce tech support is probably the fastest way to sort it out.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.I don't recall making any chances to the setup in the past, I don't have any further users on my laptop (no other users in then main p4 depot either). In the end I've just created a new one, which works fine.